# Phone refuses to allow custom rom flash

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat

I did something to my phone to where when I flash my phone with custom memory, I press the home + down + power button, it asks me if I want to flash a custom rom, and I select yes, the phone restarts itself every single time. Some needs to help me, what do I do? My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 {SGH-I337}

Comment: something is wrong with aboot which causes exit in download mode. what happens if you root with kingoroot again? this should give you back king/superuser. once you have root access you can ask how to flash custom recovery in boot mode, and how to flash stock ROM in recovery mode

Comment: try [TWRP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twrp.twrpapp) app or flash [philz touch](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2201860) recovery.img 6.58.7 from mega.nz jflte folder

Comment: I did try to use the TWRP app but when I flash TWRP it does nothing because when a rooted app tries to gain root access, nothing happens and TWRP crashes, or just hangs because I guess it waits for a response to allow root, I have tried unrooting with KingoRoot or other rooters and it unroots and when I root it seems like the root is successful, the issue is that I don't know how to fix superuser, because either the binary is reserved error is what I get or the Superuser root control app closes and crashes. My only fix for this is CF Autoroot but I don't trust it because I used it before and..

Comment: It made my apps unusable, like the apps still existed but they couldn't be accessed or opened. But if I'm gonna have to use CF Autoroot as my only choice then I guess I will back everything up if I can find a way to and then use it in case it erases my apps or makes them unusable.